# how to create regular expression based on some condition

Tags: c#, regex

i want to create a regular expression to find and replace uppercase character based on some condition.

find the starting uppercase for a group of uppercase character in a string and replace it lowercase and `*` before the starting uppercase.
If there is any lowercase following the uppercase,replace the uppercase with lowercase and `*` before the starting uppercase.

**input string** : `stackOVERFlow`

**expected output** :  `stack*over*flow`

i tried but could not get it working perfectly.

Any idea on how to create a regular expression ? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that your input/output agrees with your description.

Answer (score 4):

Well the expected inputs and outputs are slightly illogical: you're lower-casing the "f" in "flow" but not including it in the asterisk.

Anyway, the regex you want is pretty simple: `@"[A-Z]+?"`. This matches a string of one or more uppercase alpha characters, nongreedily (don't think it makes a difference either way as the matched character class is relatively narrow).

Now, to do the find/replace, you would do something like the following:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"([A-Z]+?)", "*$1*").ToLower();
```

This simply finds all occurrences of one or more uppercase alpha characters, and wherever it finds a match it replaces it with itself surrounded by asterisks. This does the surrounding but not the lowercasing; .NET Regex doesn't provide for that kind of string modification. However, since the end result of the operation should be a string with all lowercase chars, just do exactly that with a ToLower() and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

KeithS's solution can be simplified a bit

```
Regex.Replace("stackOVERFlow","[A-Z]+","*$0*").ToLower()
```

However, this will yield `stack*overf*low` including the `f` between the stars. If you want to exclude the last upper case letter, use the following expression

```
Regex.Replace("stackOVERFlow","[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])","*$0*").ToLower()
```

It will yield `stack*over*flow`

This uses the pattern `find(?=suffix)`, which finds a position before a suffix.